# How to bring this nested json into classes

Tags: json, vb.net

I have this nested structure

[image]

and want to parse it into classes. 
I have this code to get the json file and to deserialize it

```
 Public Function getDatasources(ByVal _token As String) As List(Of Results)
        Dim client = New RestClient(_baseURI)
        Dim request = New RestRequest("/datasource", Method.GET)
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token)
        request.AddHeader("environment", _environment)
        Dim jstr = client.Execute(request).Content
        Dim datasourceInfo As List(Of Results) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Results))(jstr)

        Return datasourceInfo

    End Function
```

And build this class structure

```
Public Class Results
    Public Property results As List(Of DatasourceInfos)
End Class

Public Class DatasourceInfos
    Public Property DSContainer() As List(Of DatasourceInfo)
End Class

Public Class DatasourceInfo
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property created As ULong
    Public Property modified As ULong
    Public Property creator As List(Of Creator)
    Public Property editor As List(Of Editor)
End Class

Public Class Creator
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property login As String
End Class

Public Class Editor
    Public Property email As String
    Public Property login As String
End Class
```

But running the code the object datasourceInfo is empty and I do not know why. Anyone who can help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mistaken the meaning of the JSON icons. Only square brackets `[]` denote arrays/lists. The curly brackets `{}` denote ***objects***.

- `results` is a list of `DatasourceInfo` (***not*** a list of a list).
- `DatasourceInfo.creator` is a ***single*** `Creator`, and:
- `DatasourceInfo.editor` is a ***single*** `Editor`.

Your code should be changed to:

```
Public Class Results
    Public Property results As List(Of DatasourceInfo)
End Class

Public Class DatasourceInfo
    ...your other properties...

    Public Property creator As Creator
    Public Property editor As Editor
End Class
```

The `DatasourceInfos` class (note the ***`s`*** on the end) can be removed altogether.

Comment: @ruedi : Glad I could help! Please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted :). Good luck with your project!